# Sometimes, error "ORA-00933" occurs when using entity framework to query to Oracle DB but when I restart the webapp, it works

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

I have used Entity Framework 5 for Oralce Database of web-based application. Sometimes (rarely happens), error "ORA-00933" occurs but when I restart the webapp, it gets work again.
This is log:

> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while
>   executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>   ---> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended    at
>   OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl
>   connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors,
>   OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB,
>   Boolean bFirstIterationDone)    at
>   OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String
>   commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType
>   commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl,
>   OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64
>   clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]
>   scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection&
>   bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64&
>   internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML,
>   Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)    at
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean
>   requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)    at
>   System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>   at MOS.DAO.HisTreatment.HisTreatmentGet.GetById(Int64 id,
>   HisTreatmentSO search)

This is the code "HisTreatmentGet.GetById":

```
HIS_TREATMENT result = null;
try
{
    bool valid = true;
    using (var ctx = new AppContext())
    {
        var query = ctx.HIS_TREATMENT.AsQueryable().Where(p => p.ID == id);
        ...
        result = query.SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ....
}
return result;
```

I've tried searching on google but there's no solution. Anyone can give me advices?

Comment: Hi, i have a similar problem. EF throws that 00933 error, but it happens "randomly" (logs didn't show any time pattern), and only on some requests. Like ctx.PHOTO.Where(x=>x.date > datetime.now.addDays(-1)) doesnt work, but ctx.PHOTO.Where(x=>x.date > datetime.now.addDays(-2)) does.

I'm looking for answers, but I only found your post so far.

Answer (score 5):

There is a bug in the provider for Entity Framework from Oracle.

> Seems like the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.SqlGen.SqlSelectStatement.Top_s is the culprit that gets borrowed by a parallel query. This should either be thread static (quick hack) or moved to some contextual state (proper fix, e.g. to SqlGenerator).

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3728543

No answer from Oracle support. That being said, there is a new version of the nuget package : [12.2.110](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/12.2.1100). You may give it a try and check if the issue is fixed.